# Mixing RewriteRule and ProxyPass in Apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, load-balancing, mod-proxy

I was working on debugging an issue today related to mixing `mod_proxy` and `mod_rewrite` together and I ended up having to use `balancer://mycluster` in the `RewriteRule` in order to stop receiving a 404 error from Apache. I have two questions:

1) Is there any other way to get the rewritten URL to go through the balancer without adding `balancer://mycluster` into the `RewriteRule`?

2) Is there a way to define all the parameters I defined in `ProxyPass` (stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid scolonpathdelim=On lbmethod=bytraffic nofailover=Off) in either the `<Proxy>` or `RewriteRule`? I'm concerned the requests that match the new `RewriteRule` won't load balance in the same fashion as those that go through `ProxyPass` (like `/app1/something.do`)?

Below are the relevant sections of the httpd.conf. I am using Apache 2.2.

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all

    BalancerMember ajp://my.domain.com:8009 route=node1
    BalancerMember ajp://my.domain.com:8009 route=node2
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /app1 balancer://mycluster/app1 stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid scolonpathdelim=On lbmethod=bytraffic nofailover=Off
ProxyPassReverse /app1 ajp://my.domain.com:8009/app1
```

...

```
RewriteRule ^/static/cms/image/(.*)\.(.*) balancer://mycluster/app1/$1.$2 [P,L]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like I can use the [ProxySet](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyset) directive so the URL's that match the RewriteRule load balance in the same fashion.

```
<Proxy balancer://mycluster>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all

    BalancerMember ajp://my.domain.com:8009 route=node1
    BalancerMember ajp://my.domain.com:8009 route=node2

    ProxySet stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid scolonpathdelim=On lbmethod=bytraffic nofailover=Off
</Proxy>
```